# How to use methods to pass information between classes

Tags: java

I am currently taking my first Java course and am having a hard time understanding methods and how you can you them to pass information between classes.

I have written code for an assignment i have but i can not figure out for the life of me how to pass taxableIncome and tax from one class to another.

Could you please look at my code and point me in the right direct or tell me what i am doing wrong? I have been trying to get this to work all week but have not had luck. Please make your responses understandable to someone who has little knowledge of Java currently enter code here.

My first class code is following:

```
/**
 * This program will ask the user for their taxable income, and display that number based on calculations done in the TaxCalculator Class.
 */

import java.util.*;

public class TaxCalculatorTester{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        double taxableIncome = 0; //declare and initialize taxable income
        double tax = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program will calculate how much you owe in taxes based on your income."); 
        System.out.println("Please enter your taxable income for this year.");
        taxableIncome = input.nextDouble( );

        TaxCalculator taxObject = new TaxCalculator();
        taxObject.CalculateTax(tax);

        System.out.println("You owe " + tax + " in taxes.");
        System.out.println("Please note this is just a estimate and acutal amount due may differ.");
    }
}
```

The second class code that actual calculates everything is as follows:

```
/**
 * This program will calculate how much tax a user owes based on the user input taxable income which is pulled from the TaxCalculatorTester class.
 */

import java.util.*;

class TaxCalculator{

    static double CalculateTax (double taxableIncome){
        double tax = 0.0;


        if (taxableIncome < 9526)
          tax = taxableIncome * .10;
        else if (taxableIncome <= 38700.99)
          tax = taxableIncome * .12;
        else if (taxableIncome <= 82500.99)
          tax = taxableIncome * .22;
        else if (taxableIncome <= 157500.99)
          tax = (taxableIncome * .24);
        else if (taxableIncome <= 200000.99)
          tax = taxableIncome * .32;
        else if (taxableIncome <= 500000.99)
          tax = taxableIncome * .35;
        else
          tax = taxableIncome * .37;
     return tax;
    }
}
```

Comment: The parameter is named `taxableIncome`. But what you're passing is the variable `tax`, whose value is always 0. And you ignore what the CalculateTax method returns, i.e. the result of the computation. Note that methods should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Terrible title. Summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: It's a static method so you don't instantiate it, you just call it directly through reference.

Also you should save it to a variable.

double calculatedTax = TaxCalculator.CalculateTax(tax);

Comment: pass `taxableIncome` (not `tax`) to `CalculateTax()`: `tax = taxObject.CalculateTax(taxableIncome);` then produces expected result.

Comment: As more of a side note you should take a look at [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Methods should not start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your:

```
TaxCalculator taxObject = new TaxCalculator();
taxObject.CalculateTax(tax);
```

in to:

```
tax = TaxCalculator.CalculateTax(taxableIncome);
```

Method `CalculateTax` (which name should start from lower case) is `static` so you can call it without creating object of containing class (`CalculateTax` in your case).

In your code you are passing `tax` as argument of `CalculateTax` method, but `tax` is `0`. You have to pass value typed by user so `taxableIncome`.

Also, you have to remember to assign somewhere value returned by method `CalculateTax`, because in your code you are passing data, method is doing some calculation and you don't care about result (returned value).